# Add numbers without carrying

Tags: python, math

Lets say I have two numbers,

Number 1:

```
1646
```

Number 2:

```
2089
```

You see adding them left to right without the carry on adds up to 3625 how would I do this in python? I'm not sure but I need it to add 9+6 which is 15 but not to carry on the 1 when it adds 8+4 is there any way to add like this in python? And the end result i'm looking for is

```
3625
```

Since it doesn't carry on remaining numbers

Comment: you can try spliting the numbers by converting them to strings and adding them separately.

Comment: yes, but is their any more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Does it matter if there is a more efficient way of doing it? Surely that would be the most legible, straightforward, and easy-to-understand way of doing it.

Comment: When you say efficient, do you mean *fast* or *fewest lines of code*?  Because if you mean the first, is it really going to slow down your code?

Comment: Hm, a little of both but I won't want a huge code to do this, roipii has that but I'm not sure how the zip works or what it's exactly doing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will work with varying N of integers of varying lengths:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

nums = [1646,
        2089,
         345]

revs = [str(n)[-1::-1] for n in nums]        # nums as reversed strings
izl  = izip_longest(*revs, fillvalue = '0')  # zip the digits together
xsum = lambda ds: str(sum(map(int, ds)))[-1] # digits -> last digit of their sum
rres = ''.join(xsum(ds) for ds in izl)       # result, but as reversed string
res  = int(rres[-1::-1])                     # result: 3960
```

Similar idea, but using `map` rather than `izip_longest`. I like this one better.

```
revs = [str(n)[-1::-1] for n in nums]           # nums as reversed strings
dsum = lambda *ds: sum(int(d or 0) for d in ds) # str-digits -> their sum
sums = map(dsum, *revs)[-1::-1]                 # digit sums, in order
ones = [str(s % 10) for s in sums]              # last digits of the sums
res  = int(''.join(ones))                       # result: 3960
```

Comment: Clever to flip it around and use izip_longest.  :)

Answer (score 4):

Because I like to take poetic license with open-ended requests for 'more efficient':

```
In [49]: a,b = 1646,2089

In [50]: ''.join(str(sum(map(int,x)))[-1] for x in zip(str(a),str(b)))
Out[50]: '3625'
```

Comment: hm, that looks good but can you explain what the zip is doing?

Comment: @ruler you take 2 iterables and 'zip' them together (like a zipper) to make a number of 2-tuples equal to the length of the shortest iterable.  But honestly this is more useful as code golf than anything else.  Write your own function that does the above - albeit in more lines - that a human can actually read.  Just because I managed to do it in one line does not make it 'pythonic'.

Comment: All respect to roppi, this is very clever ([golfy ;)](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com)) code, but @ruler its not code you should consider for production for the very reason that you aren't sure what its doing. It will fall down if the strings are different lengths.

Comment: @roipi can enumerate be used for this?

Comment: I think it's a bit clearer without the map: `int(''.join(str(int(a)+int(b))[-1] for a, b in izip(str(n1), str(n2))) )`

Answer (score 4):

This will work even if the numbers of digits is not the same in both the numbers.

```
num1, num2, i, temp = 1646, 2089, 10, 0
total = num1 + num2
while num1 or num2:
    if (num1 % 10) + (num2 % 10) > 9: temp += i
    num1, num2, i = num1 // 10, num2 // 10, i * 10

print total - temp
```

**Output**

```
3625
```

Answer (score 3):

The following code demonstrates what you want, but please just consider this as a hint. The var names and lack of exception handling will jeopardize your real code.

```
import operator

n1 = 1646
n2 = 2089

l1 = [int(x) for x in str(n1)]
l2 = [int(x) for x in str(n2)]

res1 = map(operator.add, l1, l2)
res2 = [str(x)[-1] for x in res1]

num = "".join(res2)

print int(num)
```

Comment: Might I recommend changing the last loop to `num = "".join(res2)`?

Comment: @SethMMorton Ofcourse:) I'm new to python too, I'll change it now.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of ugly because I do not know how to index a digit in an integer, only a string, but it works.

If the two strings are always the same size:

```
A = str(1646)
B = str(2089)
result = ""

for i in range(0,len(A)):
    result += str((int(A[i]) + int(B[i]))%10)

result = int(result)
```

If the two strings are not always the same size, find which one is bigger (length wise). Say the length of the biggest is X and the others length is Y where X > Y. Append the first X-Y indexes of the bigger string onto result, then repeat the above with the remaining digits.

Comment: You also want to only take the units digit after adding `int(A[i]) + int(B[i])`, otherwise if the result is > 9...

Answer (score 1):

The numbers might be different length, so convert both to strings, reverse order (makes indexing easier), reverse using extended slice ([::-1], [Reverse a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python)), reverse back,

```
result=""
A=str(1646)[::-1]
B=str(2089)[::-1]
for ndx in range(0,max(len(A),len(B)):
    result += str(int(A[ndx])+int(B[ndx]))
resut = int(result[::-1])
```

You can get carry pretty easily, and handle unequal length strings (explicitly),

```
#!/bin/env python
a=1646
b=20893
A=str(a)[::-1]
B=str(b)[::-1]
lenA = len(A)
lenB = len(B)
length = max(lenA,lenB)
print "length: "+str(length)

#string add,no carry
total=""
for ndx in range(0,length):
    digit = 0
    if(ndx<lenA):
        digit += int(A[ndx])
    if(ndx<lenB):
        digit += int(B[ndx])
    digit = digit%10
    #print "digit: "+str(digit)+", carry: "+str(carry)
    total += str(digit)
print "a: " +str(a)+"+b: " +str(b)
result = total[::-1]
resut = int(result)
print "result: " +str(result)

#string add,with carry
total=""
carry=0
for ndx in range(0,length):
    digit = carry
    if(ndx<lenA):
        digit += int(A[ndx])
    if(ndx<lenB):
        digit += int(B[ndx])
    carry = digit/10
    digit = digit%10
    #print "digit: "+str(digit)+", carry: "+str(carry)
    total += str(digit)
if(carry>0):
    total += str(carry)
    #print "digit: "+str(digit)+", carry: "+str(carry)
print "a: " +str(a)+"+b: " +str(b)
result = total[::-1]
resut = int(result)
print "result: " +str(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

First convert the numbers into strings so we can iterate over the digits:

```
>>> n1 = str(1646)
>>> n2 = str(2089)
```

We can then add the corresponding digits then do `%10` to get the last digit. All numbers which result from adding two integers *0-9* will be *<= 18*, therefore `%10` will always return the last digit.

```
>>> [(int(a)+int(b))%10 for a,b in zip(n1,n2)]
[3, 6, 2, 5]
```

We then convert each int into a string, join the digits and convert back to a int:

```
>>> int(''.join(map(str,((int(a)+int(b))%10 for a,b in zip(n1,n2)))))
3625
```

Or alternatively (converting the digits as you go):

```
>>> int(''.join(str((int(a)+int(b))%10) for a,b in zip(n1,n2)))
3625
```

Use `izip_longest(...,fillvalue="0")` to add numbers of different lengths.